# Jupyter Notebook alt+D shortcut collision

Tags: ipython, jupyter, jupyter-notebook

I wanted to try out Jupyter notebooks, but quickly ran into problems with it since my keyboard layout uses `alt+d` and `alt+f` to insert `(` and `)` which doesn't work. All my other modifiers are also based on `alt+{letter}` and they all work, but for some reason `alt+d` and `alt+f` are getting swallowed by something. However I can't find any shortcut documented for those two combinations either.

I've added the following to `~/.ipython/profile_default/static/custom/custom.js`

```
$([IPython.events]).on("app_initialized.NotebookApp", function () {
    // No idea what these do, but the mess with my keyboard layout
    IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.remove_shortcut("Alt-d");
    IPython.keyboard_manager.command_shortcuts.remove_shortcut("Alt-f");
});
```

But this doesn't seem to have any effect even after a server restart and browser reload.

Thanks

Comment: I'm pretty sure Jupyter doesn't do anything with those shortcuts, though it's possible that Codemirror, the code editor component in the notebook, does. But when I try it in my browser, Alt-d and Alt-f are browser shortcuts, not anything in the editor.

Comment: Possibly it could be the fact that the editor doesn't seem to be using actual input fields, but instead some other solution, maybe this causes the browser to not disable certain shortcuts that shouldn't be enabled when entering text.

Comment: @ThomasK Yeah it seems like this is a Codemirror shortcut to delete a word https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/blob/1cbf1f64001b36dc7115f6a36c0f919f59c434fa/lib/codemirror.js#L2911. Do you know if it's possible to remove those shortcuts too?

Comment: I suspect it probably is, but I don't know how, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after some amount of digging I figured out what causes this. The problem is not in the jupyter notebook, but is caused by a shortcut in the underlying CodeMirror editor. As seen [here](https://github.com/codemirror/CodeMirror/blob/1cbf1f64001b36dc7115f6a36c0f919f59c434fa/lib/codemirror.js#L2911) CodeMirror adds shortcuts for Alt +d and Alt + e. The way to disable these is putting the following in `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.js`

```
delete CodeMirror.keyMap.emacsy["Alt-F"]; 
delete CodeMirror.keyMap.emacsy["Alt-D"];
```